# Why doesn't API.play work on playerReady in Videogular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, videogular

I have an Angular SPA with 2 views. When I go from view 1 to view 2, a video in view 2 should start playing. I use Videogular and view 2's controller contains this:

```
 this.onPlayerReady = function (API) {
     this.API = API;
     alert(API.currentState);
     API.play(); 
     alert(API.currentState);
 };
```

The first alert says 'stop' and the next alert says 'play'. BUT the video doesn't play. The poster image has disappeared, but the video is stuck. 
Do I have to demand more than playerReady, before I use API.play?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the play/pause control shows the pause symbol. When I click that, the video plays allright. I had a suspicion, that the view's slide animation might interfere. I removed the animation, but no luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is now solved: I had to use onCanPlay/vg-can-play in stead of onPlayerReady.

NB: onCanPlay is not mentioned in [the tutorial to Videogular API](http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/videogular-api/)